# Extracting distance from suggested routes in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I set this:

```
provideRouteAlternatives: true
```

and I get alternative routes in my **directionsPanel**

I can get the main route distance in this way:

```
var myroute = result.routes[0];
for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
  total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
}
```

So, I can calculate the fuel consumption, for example.

But when I click on alternative routes, displayed on **directionsPanel**, I can't figure out how to get the new distance.

Answer (score 0):

The main route is result.routes[0]. The first alternate is result.routes[1].

Comment: Thank you very much! But how to detect which route is clicked on **directionsPanel**?

Comment: And to answer your question, I don't know of any way to detect which route is clicked in the default display.  Probably have to render the display of the alternate routes yourself, and add a click listener to it.

Comment: I added a little sample for constructing  a polyline from `overview_path`. Pasting here did not make sense, so I added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct  polylines with `overview_path`. Here is an example, for the first route, but you can easily extend this to a for loop and have different polylines and handler functions.

```
      path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        strokeColor: 'green',
        strokeWeight: 4
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'click', function(me) {
        alert('Click');
       });
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (i=0;i<path.length;i++){
         polyline.getPath().push(path[i]);
         bounds.extend(path[i]);
      }
      polyline.setMap(map);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
```

gives you the click listener.

Comment: If you [request alternate routes and use a "panel" to display them in](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_alternates.html), you get a listing of the alternatives which you can click on to change the rendered route.  That was what I was talking about, not clicking on the route.

Comment: Thank you guys! I think that your examples are the thing what I need. I'll test them soon. 
Thank you!